# Initializing 'i' to 1 in the array yields desired values, but setting 'i' to 0 produces unexpected unrelated numbers

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, cs50

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    int length;
    do{
        length = get_int("Length: ");
    }
    while (length < 1);

    int twice[length];

    twice[0] = 1;
    printf("%i\n", twice[0]);

    for (int i=1; i < length; i++)
    {
        twice[i] = 2*twice[i-1];
        printf("%i\n", twice[i]);
    }
}
```

The goal of this code is this:
User will prompt a value which will be the range of the array and array will start from 1 and multiple the previous value and assign it to the next array.
Let's say user promted 5, the output will be:

```
Length: 5
1
2
4
8
16
```

This code works fine but when i change `int i = 1` to `int i = 0` i get this result:

```
Length: 5
1
43864
87728
175456
350912
701824
```

Why do I get those numbers and even though i didn't assign them?

I expect to see where those numbers come from.

Comment: `twice[i] = 2*twice[i-1];` ==> `twice[ 0 ] = 2*twice[ -1 ];`... Now can you see what's going wrong??

Comment: What value is `twice[i-1]` for `i=0`? Is it still in the array? Accessing arbitrary memory addresses will yield arbitrary (undefined) results.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/sanitizers/asan?view=msvc-170